# Question to show the following function in $L^{2}$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

If $\varphi \in C^{0}(\bar{\Omega}) \cap C^{2}(\bar{\Omega} \setminus \left\{0\right\})$, does it imply that $\varphi \in L^{2}(\Omega)$?

Answer (score 1):

If $\Omega$ is bounded, then yes. If $\Omega$ is unbounded, then no.
If $\Omega$ is bounded and $\varphi\in C^0(\bar{\Omega})$, then $\varphi$ is bounded on $\bar{\Omega}$ and hence $\varphi\in L^2(\Omega)$. If $\Omega$ is any unbounded domain, then you can find even a $C^\infty$ smooth radial function $\varphi(x)=f(|x|)$ that growths so fast that $\varphi\not\in L^2(\Omega)$.

Comment: What if $\Delta \varphi =0 $ in $\Omega$?

Comment: I think I figured the answer. Thanks piotr

Comment: in fact, If $\Omega$ is bounded, I just need $\varphi \in C^{0}(\bar{\Omega})$ to have $\varphi \in L^{2}(\Omega)$, correct?

Comment: I modified my answer so it should solve your problem.

Comment: I think it would be more appropriate to ask this question on Math.StackExchange. Mathoverflow is for research level problems and this one is not.